# How to format Excel Cell as Date in Apache POI as with the Format Painter operation in Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am pretty new to Apache POI, I wonder how to do that Format Painter operation to format a cell into Date format, each time when I try to copy the date format of cell, in POI, it can only give me Numeric, I wonder how can I keep the date format?

```
    // Get source cell type and style
    CellType type_from = cell_from.getCellTypeEnum();
    CellStyle style_from = cell_from.getCellStyle();

    // Get source cell data format
    short df = style_from.getDataFormat();

    // Change dest cell cell type, set format on it
    cell_to.setCellType(type_from);
    CellStyle style_to = cell_to.getCellStyle();
    style_to.setDataFormat(df);
    cell_to.setCellStyle(style_to);
```

And I need to change some other style, like border, background color, font italic, etcs. Could you give out one example: create one xlsx file, set 1A to number( say 10 ), 2A to text ("10") 1B to date(01/12/2018), 2B to 10000(just a number), then try to turn 2A into number with font 16 and green cell background, and turn 2B into date with same format as 1B but italic font.

Comment: That code looks broadly as I'd expect, what exactly abouot it isn't working?

Comment: @Gagravarr The destination cell format can not be paint as Date but always Number

Comment: Are you perhaps running out of cell styles? Why not just apply the very same style from the source cell to the destination one?

Comment: @Gagravarr Sorry, I did not quite get it. What means running out cell styles?

Comment: "What means running out cell styles?": [Too many different cell formats](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213904/you-receive-a-too-many-different-cell-formats-error-message-in-excel) "This problem occurs when the workbook contains more than approximately 4,000 different combinations of cell formats in Excel 2003 or 64,000 different combinations in Excel 2007 and later versions." May be you are using `XSSF` which allows approx. 64,000 different cell formats but the `public **short** getDataFormat()` cannot even get more than 32,767 since this is `short` ' s max value.

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks for reply. The source cell format is like 10-Jan-2018, and the .getDataFormat() is 14, I am not sure why this can not be given to the destination cell style. Anyway, forget how I do this, is there anyway else can achieve my goal?

Comment: The `DataFormat`14 is one of the [BuiltinFormats](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html). So it should always be the short date format set in operating system locale in control panel. At least for me it is. So I cannot reproducing your problem. But what goal exactly? You are talking about a format painter. So why not simply `cell_to.setCellStyle(style_from);` without manipulating the single cell styles? Also what apache poi version we are talking about here?

Comment: @AxelRichter Because I need to change some other style, like border, background color, font italic, etcs. Could you give out one example: create one xlsx file, set 1A to number( say 10 ), 2A to text ("10") 1B to date(01/12/2018),  2B to 10000(just a number), then try to turn 2A into number with font 16 and green  cell background,  and turn 2B into date with same format as 1B but italic font. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

As said in comment already, the issue is not reproducible having your code snippet only. That shows why [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are necessary.

I suspect the following: You are having the snippet in a loop and do changing the same style `style_to` multiple times having different `style_from` as source. This is possible since multiple cells `cell_to` may sharing the same style.

Manipulating cell styles for `Excel` spreadsheets is not as simple as one may think. The cell styles are stored on workbook level and are [limited](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) to 64,000 unique cell formats/cell styles in modern `Excel` versions. So one must be careful with new creating cell styles. At least one should not trying creating a new cell style for each single cell.

`Apache poi` provides [CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) which has various utility functions that make working with a cells and rows easier. The various methods that deal with style's allow you to create your `CellStyle`s as you need them. When you apply a style change to a cell, the code will attempt to see if a style already exists that meets your needs. If not, then it will create a new style. This is to prevent creating too many styles. What lacks until now is the same utility functions for dealing with fonts. Fonts also are on workbook level and so also should not being created without care.

The following example provides utility functions for creating fonts too.

It takes the `ExcelTest.xlsx` as you had described in your last comment and makes the changings you also had described there. It also makes some additional changings to show how the utility functions are working.

Source:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ExcelSetCellStyleDataFormat {

 //method for getting current font from cell
 private static Font getFont(Cell cell) {
  Workbook wb = cell.getRow().getSheet().getWorkbook();
  CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
  return wb.getFontAt(style.getFontIndex());
 }

 private enum FontProperty {
  BOLD, COLOR, FONTHEIGHT, FONTNAME, ITALIC, STRIKEOUT, TYPEOFFSET, UNDERLINE
 }

 //method for getting font having special settings additional to given source font
 private static Font getFont(Workbook wb, Font fontSrc, Map<FontProperty, Object> fontproperties) {
  boolean isBold = fontSrc.getBold();
  short color = fontSrc.getColor();
  short fontHeight = fontSrc.getFontHeight();
  String fontName = fontSrc.getFontName();
  boolean isItalic = fontSrc.getItalic();
  boolean isStrikeout = fontSrc.getStrikeout();
  short typeOffset = fontSrc.getTypeOffset();
  byte underline = fontSrc.getUnderline();

  for (FontProperty property : fontproperties.keySet()) {
   switch (property) {
    case BOLD:
     isBold = (boolean)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case COLOR:
     color = (short)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case FONTHEIGHT:
     fontHeight = (short)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case FONTNAME:
     fontName = (String)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case ITALIC:
     isItalic = (boolean)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case STRIKEOUT:
     isStrikeout = (boolean)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case TYPEOFFSET:
     typeOffset = (short)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case UNDERLINE:
     underline = (byte)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
   }
  }

  Font font = wb.findFont(isBold, color, fontHeight, fontName, isItalic, isStrikeout, typeOffset, underline);
  if (font == null) {
   font = wb.createFont();
   font.setBold(isBold);
   font.setColor(color);
   font.setFontHeight(fontHeight);
   font.setFontName(fontName);
   font.setItalic(isItalic);
   font.setStrikeout(isStrikeout);
   font.setTypeOffset(typeOffset);
   font.setUnderline(underline);
  }

  return font;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelTest.xlsx"));

  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

  Row row = null;
  Cell cell = null;
  Font font = null; 
  Map<String, Object> styleproperties = null;
  Map<FontProperty, Object> fontproperties = null;

  //turn cell A2 into numeric, font size 16pt and green fill color:
  //get cell A2
  row = CellUtil.getRow(1, sheet);
  cell = CellUtil.getCell(row, 0);

  //get old cell value and set it as numeric
  String cellvalue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell); 
  cell.setCellValue(Double.valueOf(cellvalue));

  //get the needed font
  fontproperties = new HashMap<FontProperty, Object>();
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.FONTHEIGHT, (short)(16*20));
  font = getFont(wb, getFont(cell), fontproperties);

  //set new cell style properties
  styleproperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  styleproperties.put(CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat("General"));
  styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FILL_FOREGROUND_COLOR, IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
  styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FILL_PATTERN, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FONT, font.getIndex());
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, styleproperties);

  //get data format from B1
  row = CellUtil.getRow(0, sheet);
  cell = CellUtil.getCell(row, 1);
  short dataFormatB1 = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat();

  //turn B2 into same data format as B1 and italic font:
  //get cell B2
  row = CellUtil.getRow(1, sheet);
  cell = CellUtil.getCell(row, 1);

  //get the needed font
  fontproperties = new HashMap<FontProperty, Object>();
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.ITALIC, true);
  font = getFont(wb, getFont(cell), fontproperties);

  //set new cell style properties
  styleproperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  styleproperties.put(CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, dataFormatB1);
  styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FONT, font.getIndex());
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, styleproperties);

  //set new cell D6 having special font settings
  row = CellUtil.getRow(5, sheet);
  cell = CellUtil.getCell(row, 3);
  fontproperties = new HashMap<FontProperty, Object>();
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.BOLD, true);
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.COLOR, IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.FONTHEIGHT, (short)(20*20));
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.FONTNAME, "Courier New");
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.STRIKEOUT, true);
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.UNDERLINE, Font.U_DOUBLE);
  font = getFont(wb, getFont(cell), fontproperties);
  styleproperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FONT, font.getIndex());
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, styleproperties);
  cell.setCellValue("new cell");

  //set new cell C4 having special font settings
  row = CellUtil.getRow(3, sheet);
  cell = CellUtil.getCell(row, 2);
  fontproperties = new HashMap<FontProperty, Object>();
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.BOLD, true);
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.COLOR, IndexedColors.DARK_RED.getIndex());
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.FONTHEIGHT, (short)(42*20));
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.FONTNAME, "Times New Roman");
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.ITALIC, true);
  font = getFont(wb, getFont(cell), fontproperties);
  styleproperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FONT, font.getIndex());
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, styleproperties);
  //set rich textt string into that cell
  RichTextString richString = new XSSFRichTextString("E = m c2");
                                                    //^0     ^7
  fontproperties = new HashMap<FontProperty, Object>();
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.TYPEOFFSET, Font.SS_SUPER);
  font = getFont(wb, getFont(cell), fontproperties);
  richString.applyFont(7, 8, font);
  cell.setCellValue(richString);

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelTestNew.xlsx"));
  wb.close();
 }  
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused by this answer. The OP was asking about how to format the cell with a date format. This answer is mainly about formatting fonts. Would be good to make it much clearer exactly where this is happening, if it is at all.

Comment: @chrismacp: The really objective of Kuan was given in it's last comment. I've updated the question appropriate.

Comment: Ah yes! Missed that completely. I was just trying to find out how the date format of B1 was set but it doesn't ever appear to be.

Comment: @chrismacp: The cell `B1` is already stored in initial `ExcelTest.xlsx` and is a date already. So it must have set to date format already.