# Apache POI DataFormat limitations vs method invocations

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Java 8 and Apache POI 4.x here. I've found [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49438595/5235665) that you can only get 64K different data formats via `dataFormat.getFormat(...)`. But does that mean you can call `dataFormat.getFormat(...)` *any* number of times, so long as your app is using 64K (or less) different data formats? Or does it mean you can only apply formatting (and thus call `dataFormat.getFormat(...)` 64K times before you start getting errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["Too many different cell formats"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/too-many-different-cell-formats-in-excel) error results because of a `Excel` limitation on different cell formats. This only has indirectly to do with different data formats since a cell may have not only data formats set in it's  cell format but font formats, border formats and interior formats (colors) too. The limitation says: You cannot have more than 64,000 different cell formats in one `Excel` workbook in current `Excel`versions. Different cell formats mean different in either data format, font format, border format, interior format, ...

So theoretically you could have more than 64,000 different data formats but you cannot use more than 64,000 of them in different cell styles of one workbook.

The class [DataFormat](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormat.html) of `apache poi` uses a `short` to index different data formats. Since a `short` has a max value of 32,767 and the index starts with 0, you cannot create more than 32,768 different data formats in one `Workbook` using `apache poi`.

Note: All this is about **different** formats. So you can call [DataFormat.getFormat](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormat.html#getFormat-java.lang.String-) as often as needed without getting an error, as long as there are no more than 32,768 **different** data formats needed.

For example you can call [CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html#setCellStyleProperty-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-):

```
...
Workbook workbook = ...
DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
...
... {
 Cell cell = ...
 ...
 CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00"));
 ...
}
...
```

as often as needed, even in a loop for much more than 64,000 cells, as there `dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00")` always gets only the same data format index multiple times.